# How to mock a spring mvc contorller class which extends a abstract basecontroller?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

**Actual Controller**

```
public class Program extends AbstractBaseController{

  @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView Search(ModelAndView mav) {
    logger.info("Program controller");
    //load Programs Drop down.
    ProgramDTO programs = programDelegate.getPrograms(getInsid());         
    mav.addObject("programs", programs);
    mav.addObject("Name", super.getName());
    mav.setViewName("search");
    return mav;
  }
}
```

I am using Mockito and Spring Test framework.

Test Controller:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/springmvc-beans-ui.xml",
                                   "classpath:/appdelegate-spring-beans.xml",
                                   "classpath:/root-context.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class ProgramControllerTest{

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Mock
  ProgramDelegate TestDelegate;

  @InjectMocks
  Program ControllerTest;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(ControllerTest).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void findAll_Programs() throws Exception {
    ProDTO testPrograms = new ProDTO();

    List<String> programs = new ArrayList<String>();
    programs.add("maths");
    programs.add("science");

    List<String> InsId = new ArrayList<String>();
    InsId.add("4323");
    InsId.add("4363");

    testPrograms.setPrograms(programs);
    testPrograms.setAceInsIds(InsId);   
    when(programDelegateTest.getPrograms(1L)).thenReturn(testPrograms);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/loadprogramsearch")) 
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(view().name("search"));
  }
```

When I run this as a JUnit test it throws a `NullPointrException` on `mav.addObject("casName", super.getName());`

So how to get those abstract method calls available for my test class?

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Are you sure it's the `ModelAndView` that is `null`?

Comment: Thanks Delimanolis, the model and view is not null super.getName() this method is called from the controller and the abstract class has declared the getName as protected which makes it difficult for my test class to mock it.... is there a any way around we can mock this...

Comment: You're testing the `Program` controller. Why would you want to mock it?

Comment: I am testing the controller via standaloneSetup so i used injectmocks for the controller.